# add activatefeature bat file wspbuilder solution package

Tags: wspbuilder, feature-activation, stsadm

I am using WSPBuilder to package up my features that creates lists and libraries.

Is there a way to add a bat file with the package will activate these lists and libraries (since they are for specific subsites) after the setup is complete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call stsadm -o activatefeature, within a new batch file, once you have deployed the solution - depends on how you currently add and deploy the solution though.

Comment: I already have a bat file that do that. I was trying to avoid introducing bat file. The goal is to give the solution packages to sharepoint admin and wala everything is done magically (including feature activation where necessary).

Comment: James, Thanks for your input. I did some Google and I think there are not other way but bat file (which I already have). I wanted to piggy bag it with the solution package. Thanks Again.

Comment: Ah, understood. Yeah, your best bet is to pass the WSP and the bat the file to your admin, and instruct her to run the Bat file (she can then easily inspect the contents of the bat file if she wants to, too).